# Why did Arthur Weasley say, "Doesn't miss a trick, that man" here?

Tags: harry-potter

Arthur Weasley responded when he came to Harry Potter recieved letter
from Dumbledore:

> Arthur Weasley: Dumbledore must know you're here. **Doesn't miss a
> trick, that man**.
>
> Fred: No.
>
> George: This lot won't come cheap.

Why did Arthur Weasley say, "Doesn't miss a trick, that man" here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"[Doesn't miss a trick](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/someone-doesnt-miss-a-trick)" is common slang for someone being clever, with an implication that they don't make mistakes.

> If you say that someone does not miss a trick, you mean that they always know what is happening and take advantage of every situation.

In short, he says that Dumbledore knows what he's doing.